# How to make vertical scroll iPhone 5 compatible

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I made vertical scroll top to bottom repeatedly.But, on iPhone5 there is some lagging issue.

How can I make it work on iphone 5 smoothly

Here is the code:

```
-(void)scrollBackground:(ccTime)dt
{
    CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    CGPoint pos1 = mBG1.position;
    CGPoint pos2 = mBG2.position;

    pos1.y -= MM_BG_SPEED_DUR;
    pos2.y -= MM_BG_SPEED_DUR;

    if(pos1.y <=-((s.height*0.5f) ) )
    {
        pos1.y = (pos2.y + mBG2.contentSize.height)  ;
    }

    if(pos2.y <=-((s.height*0.5f) ) )
    {
        pos2.y = (pos1.y + mBG1.contentSize.height) ;
    }

    mBG1.position = pos1;
    mBG2.position = pos2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cocos2d 2.0 itself not support iPhone5 resolution. Manually you need to handle.

```
#define IS_IPHONE5 (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?NO:YES)

#define TEX_GAME_BG   (IS_IPHONE5) ? ( @"bg-whd.png") : ( @"bg.png")

mBG1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:TEX_GAME_BG];
```

Put these image in folder

```
bg.png         : 480x320
bg-hd.png      : 960x640
bg-whd.png     : 1136x640
bg-ipad.png    : 1024x768
bg-ipadhd.png  : 2048x1536
```

Comment: Thanks it also works...
But the above one suits better.Your code also helps. :)

Comment: unless you're using an older cocos2d there are already -widehd/-iphonehd suffixes in cocos2d

Comment: talking about cocos2d-iphone? I don't find it in appDelegate class...even in latest version. (http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/download) Thanks for the information sir.

Comment: I know ,i am responding late but sir  LearnCocos2D info is cent percent corrct

Comment: @user2264930, did u test -widehd works in iphone5? I guess they just added in appDelegate..none other place that is used...:p

Answer (score 1):

I would say your mBG1 & mBG2 (Background sprites i suppose) are the size of iPhone4 screen.
So the code lines

```
if(pos1.y <=-((s.height*0.5f) ) )
```

&

```
if(pos2.y <=-((s.height*0.5f) ) )
```

Only activate too late (Top of the screen is already empty).

You can ether add third mBG3 to cover more screen, give bigger sprites to mBG1 and mBG2(fit iPhone5 screen), or duplicate mBG1 as mBG3, and mBG2 as mBG4, to increase covered screen. If your mBG1 uses the same sprite as mBG2, adding additional mBG3 will suffice.
Code for the last case.

```
-(void)scrollBackground:(ccTime)dt
{
    CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    CGPoint pos1 = mBG1.position;
    CGPoint pos2 = mBG2.position;
    CGPoint pos3 = mBG3.position;

    pos1.y -= MM_BG_SPEED_DUR;
    pos2.y -= MM_BG_SPEED_DUR;
    pos3.y -= MM_BG_SPEED_DUR;

    if(pos1.y <=-((s.height*0.5f) ) )
    {
        pos1.y = (pos2.y + mBG2.contentSize.height)  ;
    }

    if(pos2.y <=-((s.height*0.5f) ) )
    {
        pos2.y = (pos3.y + mBG1.contentSize.height) ;
    }
    if(pos3.y <=-((s.height*0.5f) ) )
    {
        pos3.y = (pos1.y + mBG3.contentSize.height) ;
    }

    mBG1.position = pos1;
    mBG2.position = pos2;
    mBG3.position = pos3;
}
```

Comment: Hi,sorry for sounding such immature.I am new to ios gaming(cocos2d).
Can you help what size of image should i use for repeating background.
use 3 different image - bg.png,bg@2x.png and bg-568@2x.png
Someone told it might be also the reason for it

Comment: I am using same image for mBG1 and mBG2

Comment: iOS will not autoload bg-568@2x.png instead of bg.png if it is run on iPhone5, you have to manualy check for winSize if it fits iPhone5 (win size.height = 568) and load sprite with hg-568@2x.png manually.
Hope this helps :)